# How to tell what stage a CSS3 animation is at using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, webkit, listener

Eg, this is my code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-100px,0px) rotate(5deg);
    }
    50%   {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-140px,-5px) rotate(10deg);
    }
    100%   {
        -webkit-transform: translate(200px,-30px) rotate(40deg);
    }
}
```

How can I tell exactly when it's at 50%? I know I can detect when it ends but that doesn't help here.

Now... I could try to base it on time since the animation runs for 3 seconds, but that seems dodgy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are notification events for the middle stages of a single animation.

As a workaround, you could chain two separate animations (start the second animation when the first one ends using JS) and use the event at the end of the first one to know when the middle of the whole sequence was reached.

Here's an article on a work-around:

[CSS Animation Keyframe Events (Javascript solution)](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2011/05/20/css-animation-keyframe-events-javascript-solution/)

Comment: I guess that's as good as it's going to get for me, but it'll be pretty annoying having to set that up. The real animation is in 11 parts, so that'll mean 11 different durations that I'll have to first make and then chain together :(

Comment: @Phil, you can probably create one table of data for each successive animation, one index into the table and a common event handler to do all the work for you.